# dash: How can I quote the arguments ala "${(q+@)@}" in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, escape-characters, dash

I want to quote the arguments in dash (or sh, or even bash if that's not possible). I can do that with `"${(q+@)@}"` in zsh, such that `reval <sth> ...` is the same as just typing in `<sth> ...` in the terminal:

```
reval () {
    eval "$(gquote "$@")"
}
gquote () {
    print -r -- "${(q+@)@}"
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214/342404) may be useful? possibly skimming through it until "the conclusion"

Comment: not sure if that may related to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720056 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/62375262 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/62922701 maybe a combination of that answers will help you for (da)sh compatible solution

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
for arg do
        arg=$(printf '%s\n' "$arg" | sed "s/'/'\\\''/g")
        set -- "$@" "'$arg'"
        shift
done

eval "$@"
```

This adds single quotes around each positional parameter.  The loop iterates over each positional parameter, adds the current one to the end of the list, with single quotes added, and then removes the first (now processed) element.

Before adding `'$arg'` to the end of the list, any single quotes embedded in `$arg` are replaced with the string `'\''` using `sed`.

As a function called `reval`:

```bsh
reval () {
    for arg do
            arg=$(printf '%s\n' "$arg" | sed "s/'/'\\\''/g")
            set -- "$@" "'$arg'"
            shift
    done
    
    eval "$@"
}
```

(Arguments will have trailing newlines removed by this.)

In the `bash` shell, you can replace the command substitution calling `printf` and `sed` in the loop with

```bsh
arg=${arg//\'/\'\\\'\'}
```

which has the benefit of preserving trailing newlines.  Although in the `bash` shell, you may instead do

```bsh
reval () {
    eval "${@@Q}"
}
```

... where `${variable@Q}` quotes the value `$variable` so that  it's suitable for shell input. With `variable` being `@`, this applies to all positional parameters.

This is similar to what you would get with `${(q)@}` in the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
reval () {
    eval "${(q)@}"
}
```

Comment: See also [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214)