# How to create a text file with path for a script and with directory names?

Tags: linux, awk, path, text

I have a directory named `data`. Inside `data` there is one directory `samples` which has more than 50 directories and there is one shell script `testing.sh` inside `data`. The setup looks like below:

```
data
  |___ samples
         |______ PREC001
         |______ PREC003
         |______ PREC023
         |______ KRES118
         |______ TWED054
         .
         .
         .
         |______ PREC098
  |___ testing.sh
```

I want to create a `.txt` file with the path for `testing.sh` for all the directories in the `samples` and also the directory names. I am working on linux.

The created `.txt` file should look like below:

```
/data/testing.sh PREC001 samples
/data/testing.sh PREC003 samples
/data/testing.sh PREC023 samples
/data/testing.sh KRES118 samples
/data/testing.sh TWED054 samples
.
.
.
/data/testing.sh PREC098 samples
```

How to do that in linux. I actually tried with some basic commands but I couldn't get what I want. Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should just be a matter of:

```
(cd data/samples && printf '/data/testing.sh %s sample\n' *) > file.txt
```

Or to restrict to files of type *directory* only, with `zsh`:

```
printf '/data/testing.sh %s sample\n' data/samples/*(/:t) > file.txt
```

Note that it also has the advantage of reporting an error and not clobbering `file.txt` if no matching file can be found.

Replace `(/:t)` with `(-/:t)` to also include files of type *symlink* that eventually resolve to a file of type *directory*.

If that's to generate shell code to be interpreted by `sh` later, you'd also want to make sure the names of the files are properly quoted. You could replace `%s` with `%q` for that, but then you'd need to make sure the script is interpreted by `zsh` instead of `sh` as `%q` could use some form of quoting that are specific to `zsh`.

Another alternative is to use the `qq` parameter expansion flag that always uses [single quotes for quoting which are the most portable and safest quoting operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214/22565):

```
() {
  printf '/data/testing.sh %s sample\n' ${(qq)@}
} data/samples/*(/:t) > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correcly, you can do this:

```bsh
cd /pathto/data/samples || exit

for d in */; do
  echo "/data/testing.sh ${d: 1:-1} samples" >> /pathto/file.txt
done

$ cat file.txt
/data/testing.sh REC001 samples
/data/testing.sh REC003 samples
/data/testing.sh REC023 samples
...
```