# How to separate with a comma in a logfile

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, text

I have a log file as below,

```
011122111128 :16267281288 :40586200370017022 :947700000622 :919400146760221 :SSD :4065376D : :9477000006 :9170120275030 :210 :18 :002919544716189 :unknown :unknown :unknown
```

I need to print each line(always I need to get last 50 records) with a comma-separated line then I can import it as a CSV file.
Here is the required output.

```
011122111128,16267281288,40586200370017022,947700000622,919400146760221,SSD,4065376D,,9477000006,9170120275030,210,18,002919544716189,unknown,unknown,unknown
```

Here is what I tried but this prints the first value only and it not takes the last 50 records also. Can someone help me with the below?

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /log
```

Comment: What do you mean by `always I need to get last 50 records`? Do you need to separate by a comma the last 50 records of each line (so from columns 1 to 49 will not be separated by a comma)?

Comment: No, this is a log. There are so many lines as I showed .I need last 50 records only. tail -50.

Comment: Btw it seems the site is not working well for the moment. Your question (unless in my case) is not visible in the `Questions Section`. I was able to found your question by using `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723200` (I typed the number) and there are more recent questions whose can be acceded by changing `723200` for `723199` for example.

Comment: And thanks for the clarification! I will try to provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get the last `50` records to convert to a `csv` file (comma separated) then you should use:

```bash
tail -50 /log | sed 's/\s:/,/g' > /some_path/data.csv
```

Comment: I tried, But this prints whole the file. and the output is not as expected. Please note that /log is always updating file.

Comment: I have another solution then, if you only want to get the last 50 records and save the output into another file (it seems a csv file).

Comment: Great!!! Now it worked..

Comment: @edublog glad this worked for you!