# yt-dlp: You Are Using Unsupported Version Of Python

Tags: linux

yt-dlp keeps me giving this error:

OS: Centos 7
Server Running on: Litespeed/Cyberpanel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yt-dlp/yt_dlp/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contextvars'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/bin/yt-dlp/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/bin/yt-dlp/yt_dlp/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
Exception: You are using an unsupported version of Python. Only Python versions 3.7 and above are supported by yt-dlp
```

When I run python-V command, it gives me following version which is indeed above v3.7

[image]

But, when i run python3 command, it gives me this:

[image]

I'm still confused what I should do... I've installed updated version of Python. However, python3 still shows up python v3.6

In fact, If I add aliases, it works fine, but other users in the same computer won't be able to access the yt-dlp via php exec() function.

I'm trying to use yt-dlp using php exec() function.

Comment: Add the output (to your question) of `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`. I'm assuming yo have python and python3 installed under **/usr/bin** path.

Comment: [root@vmi ~]# ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov  1 06:28 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.9
[root@vmi ~]# ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 26 20:24 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
[root@vmi ~]#

Comment: Visual Version: https://i.imgur.com/CeXROM4.png

Comment: try: `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.9` and run the `yt-dlp` command.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure what is happening to this site. Your question is no longer in `questions section` but I'm still able to access to this thread. The last question it seems was 11 hours ago.

Comment: I just noticed that there are more recent questions but this site seems to be not working successfully.

Comment: Dont know what's going around

Comment: Giving same error: https://i.imgur.com/3oAf8JO.png

Comment: Check [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/wppa5y/ytdlp_fix_for_perceived_python_version_on_ubuntu/). A possible solution is by using: `alias yt-dlp="/usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp"` (save the alias into ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc, not sure what shell you are using but I assume it's bash)

Comment: But it should be useful if you provide the output of `whereis yt-dlp` (maybe this binary file is under /usr/bin directory)