# How can I move all directories below a certain size?

Tags: move

I want to move all directories in the current directory that are below a certain size

Here, I've managed to do a selection:

```
for dir in *
do
    if [[ $(du -s "$dir" | awk '{print $1}') -le 50000 ]]
    then
      ls -l "$dir"
    fi
done
```

I now figured I should use dirname to get the directory, but somehow it complains no matter what I do;)

Do we have a neat way to do this?;)

Comment: "_I should use dirname to get the directory_" - what directory is this now referring to? You've got your sized directory (or file) in `"$dir"`

Comment: "_somehow it complains no matter what I do;)_" - you'll need to be precise with your "_what I do_" and "_it complains_" otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: `du -bd 1|while read a b ;do  if [[ $a < 50000 ]]; then echo $a;echo $b;fi;done`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v ^\\.$ | xargs -n 1 du -s | while read size name ; do if [ $size -le 50000 ] ; then mv "$name" /path/to/target/ ; fi done
```

to find every directory in the current dir below a size of 50000 and move it into the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've did the legwork properly, the place for mv command: will be right after:
ls -l "$dir"
and before "fi".

like: mv $dir /where/you/want/it/relocated

one problem might arise if you have " " in directory names(or other special chars for that matter). In case such issues are faced, you can further consult: [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379181/escape-a-variable-for-use-as-content-of-another-script) thread for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to move all folders in the same level which are smaller than the 1000 KB:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'if [ $(du -d0 {} | cut -f1) -lt 1000 ];then mv {} SOMEWHERE;fi' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-liner in your desired folder, where you suggest the folders to move without any loop.

```
mv $(ls -d */ | du --max-depth=1 | awk '$1 >4 && $1 <=600 {print $2}') /path/to/folder
```

**Explanation:**

`cmd $(command substitution) /path/to/folder`

Since you want to move folders use the `mv` command.

*Command Substitution:*

The syntax for command substitution is `$()`

Pipe one command to another command with `|` inside of the command substitution.

`ls -d */`: list all directories

`du --max-depth=1`: disk usage of the previous listed directories, without listing subdirectories (`--max-depth=1`) because `mv` moves directories with their subdirectories.

`awk '$1 >4 && $1 <=600 {print $2}'`: awk checks the output of the previous command if it's not an empty folder `$1 >4`, assumed you made a folder before inside, where you want to move (`/path/to/folder`), otherwise you can omit the `$1 >4 &&` part **and** (`&&`) checks if the folders are less than 600k with `$1 <=600`. Only these files will be printed with `{print $2}`. Of course you need to adjust the size to your desired size.

These piped commands are used inside the command substitution for the `mv` command to your `path/to/folder`, as `mv $(folders less than x k) /path/to/folder`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle arbitrary directory names, on a GNU system, you could do:

```
du --block-size=1 -l0d1 |
  perl -0 -lne '
    print $2 if /^(\d+)\t(.*)/s && $2 ne "." && $1 < 50000 * 1024' |
  xargs -r0 mv -vt /destination/directory --
```

Beware that `du`'s default block size is 512, but GNU `du` decided to change that to 1024 for some reason¹. But that changes when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment and can also be changed with the `DU_BLOCK_SIZE`, `BLOCK_SIZE` and `BLOCKSIZE` environment variables.

So best to specify it explicitly on the command line. With a block size of 1, you can specify that disk usage with byte precision which makes it easier to post-process².

With `-d1`, same as `--max-depth=1`, we get a disk usage for each subdirectory of the current working directory and the current working directory itself (there's no `--min-depth` unfortunately). That avoids running on `du` per directory but also means it's counting the size of the files in the current directory which we don't need and we need to discard with `$2 ne "."` in `perl`. Compared to doing `du -- */`, that has the a advantage of not skipping hidden directories, and of not processing symlinks to directories.

That means however we need the `-l` aka `--count-links` to count every hard link to files found in the recursive descent of those directories, as otherwise if a hard link of a given file was found in one of the subdirectories, other hard links to it would not be counted in any of the other directories. Beware that also means that hard links to a given file *within a same subdirectory* are also all counted so you could end up with a different value than when using `du -s` on a single directory.

So if your directory arborescence may contain hardlinks, it may be better to call one `du` per directory to make sure they're counted independently from each other.

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -printf '%P\0' |
  xargs -r0 -n1 du --block-size=1 -0s -- |
  perl -0 -lne '
    print $2 if /^(\d+)\t(.*)/s && $2 ne "." && $1 < 50000 * 1024' |
  xargs -r0 mv -vt /destination/directory --
```

To do something similar portably (ignoring toybox `du`¹), one could do:

```
for dir in .* *; do
  [ "$dir" = . ] || [ "$dir" = .. ] && continue
  [ -d "$dir" ] || continue
  [ -L "$dir" ] && continue
  du_output=$(
    LC_ALL=C POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 BLOCK_SIZE=512 BLOCKSIZE=512 DU_BLOCK_SIZE=512 du -s -- "$dir"
  ) || continue # don't take any decision if du fails for that dir
  LC_ALL=C awk -- '
    BEGIN {$0 = ARGV[1]; exit !($1 * 512 < 50000 * 1024)}
    ' "$du_output" || continue

  mv -- "$dir" /destination/directory
done
```

(untested).

Compared to the first approach that runs 4 commands in total (more if `mv` needs to be run several times if there's a large number of directories), that one runs up to 7 commands *per file* so is going to be a lot less efficient.

---

<sup>¹ And some other implementations targetting Linux primarily such as busybox and toybox have chosen to align with GNU `du` instead of historical practice and the standard in that regard. The worst is toybox' (as found on Android for instance) which honours none of `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, `BLOCKSIZE`, `BLOCK_SIZE` nor `DU_BLOCK_SIZE` and has `-b` (byte), `-k` (kibibyte, default), `-K` (512), `-m` (mebibyte) options instead, which means it's impossible to invoke `du` in a portable fashion if that implementation needs to be considered.</sup>

<sup>² though increases the risk of integer overflow. 512 is generally the minimum space allocation unit, so makes sense as a default unit for disk usage.</sup>