# GNU parallel: how to call exported bash function with empty string argument?

Tags: bash, string, gnu-parallel

Scenario:

```
$ process(){ echo "[$1] [$2] [$3]" ; } ; export -f process

$ process "x" "" "a.txt"
[x] [] [a.txt]
```

Here we see that the 2nd argument is empty string (expected).

```
$ find -name "*.txt" -print | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel process "x" ""
[x] [./a.txt] []
[x] [./b.txt] []
[x] [./c.txt] []
```

Here we see that the 2nd argument is the output of find (unexpected).

Expected output:

```
[x] [] [./a.txt]
[x] [] [./b.txt]
[x] [] [./c.txt]
```

How to fix?

---

Note: if the 2nd argument is changed from `""` to `"y"`, then the output of find is present as the 3rd argument (expected):

```
$ find -name "*.txt" -print | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel process "x" "y"
[x] [y] [./a.txt]
[x] [y] [./b.txt]
[x] [y] [./c.txt]
```

Why *isn't* the output of find present as the 3rd argument with `""`?

---

UPD: It seems that the solution is `\"\"`:

```
$ find -name "*.txt" -print | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel process "x" \"\"
[x] [] [./a.txt]
[x] [] [./b.txt]
[x] [] [./c.txt]
```

However, I'm not sure that this is the correct general solution. Here is the counterexample:

```
$ VAR="" ; find -name "*.txt" -print | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel process "x" "$VAR"
[x] [./a.txt] []
[x] [./b.txt] []
[x] [./c.txt] []
```

Comment: So it runs the command through a shell, interpreting quotes and whitespace. Similarly if you do `echo x | parallel process "foo bar" ""`, you'll see the output `[foo] [bar] [x]`, instead of `[foo bar] [x]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, parallel runs the command through a shell, instead of executing it directly. Well, it has to, since otherwise the shell function you're using wouldn't work.

It also means that arguments with whitespace will get split:

```
$ echo x | parallel process "foo bar" ""
[foo] [bar] [x]
```

And it doesn't really matter if you quote the individual args or the whole command:

```
$ echo x | parallel "process foo bar"
[foo] [bar] [x]
```

And you can do things like this:

```
$ echo x | parallel process '$(date +%F)'
[2024-02-29] [x] []
$ echo x | parallel "process foo bar > test.out"
$ cat test.out
[foo] [bar] [x]
```

To pass arbitrary values, you'd need to get them quoted for the shell. In Bash, you could use the `${var@Q}` expansion for variables:

```
$ var="foo bar"; echo x | parallel process "${var@Q}"
[foo bar] [x] []
```

And parallel looks to have an option to do just this:

> `--quote`
> `-q`  Quote command. If your command contains special
> characters
> that should not be interpreted by the shell (e.g. `;` `\` `|` `*`), use `--quote` to escape these. The command must be a
> simple command (see man bash) without redirections and without variable assignments.
>
> See the section QUOTING. Most people will not need this.  Quoting is disabled by default.

```
$ var="foo bar"; echo x | parallel --quote process "$var"
[foo bar] [x] []
```

Of course that will also trash redirections and such:

```
$ var="foo bar"; echo x | parallel --quote process "$var" ">test.out"
[foo bar] [>test.out] [x]
```

Of course, it will quote whitespace, so if you try to pass the command arguments as a single string, it will fail.

---

Note that when you do this

```
$ VAR="" ; ... parallel process "x" "$VAR"
```

the variable still contains just the empty string, which is what gets passed to parallel as an argument. To make it the same as `parallel process "x" \"\"`, you'd need to have hard quotes in the variable, i.e. `VAR=\"\"`, or `VAR='""'` or equivalent. Or use something like `parallel process "x" "'$VAR'"` instead. And remember that you can't blindly wrap things in quotes if the variable itself can also contain quotes. This will fail:

```
$ var="ain't so"; echo x | parallel process "'$var'"
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Thanks. I've [figured out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379190/334715) that `${var@Q}` is a possible solution. Question: in `parallel process "${var@Q}"`, is double quoting of `${var@Q}` really required?

Comment: @pmor, yes, try `var='foo * bar'` with `echo "${var@Q}"` vs. `echo ${var@Q}`. The question to ask is _not_ ["is double-quoting necessary", but "is this is one of the rare cases where I can leave the quotes out"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)