# Compare files and tell how similar they are

Tags: diff

Is there a way to compare two file and give some kind of numeric indication of their similarity?

For example, if I have two files that differ by just one character (say, a character was deleted or changed), the program ought to say something like "file X differs by 1 character."

Or if two lines are different, say "file X differs by two lines."

The best output would be something like "File X is 95% similar to file Y"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach could be to compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Here using the `Text::LevenshteinXS` `perl` module:

```
distance() {
  perl -MText::LevenshteinXS  -le 'print distance(@ARGV)' "$@"
}
```

Then:

```
$ distance foo foo
0
$ distance black blink
2
$ distance "$(cat /etc/passwd)" "$(tr a b < /etc/passwd)"
177
```

Here's a line-based implementation of the Levenshtein distance in `awk` (computes the distance in terms of number of inserted/deleted/modified lines instead of characters):

```
awk '
  {if (NR==FNR) s[++m]=$0; else t[++n]=$0}
  function min(x, y) {
    return x < y ? x : y
  }
  END {
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++) d[i,0] = i
    for(j=0;j<=n;j++) d[0,j] = j

    for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        c = s[i] != t[j]
        d[i,j] = min(d[i-1,j]+1,min(d[i,j-1]+1,d[i-1,j-1]+c))
      }
    }
    print d[m,n]
  }' file1 file2
```

You may also be interested in `diffstat`'s output:

```
$ diff -u /etc/passwd <(tr a b < /etc/passwd) | diffstat
 13 |  114 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------------------
 1 file changed, 57 insertions(+), 57 deletions(-)
```

Comment: would the above be applicable here?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120343/brace-compression

Comment: @mikeserv, probably not, we're only computing a distance here. Recursively factorising similarities in strings is another level I would say.

Comment: Diffstat is pretty cool!